# I am using Live sdk for uploading files to One drive and received a Alert from google :

Tags: java, android

**Vulnerable classes:**
Google Play Warning: SSL Error Handler Vulnerability

> com.microsoft.live.AuthorizationRequest$OAuthDialog$AuthorizationWebViewClient

However, I have checked my code and i am not using any of the web view and also i don't have any method as

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
}
```

I don't know how to handle this. Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Looks like there has been some more information you did not post. The class is vulnerable for what?

Comment: Google just giving error as SSL error handler Vulnerability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched and found answer for my own question:
In old Onedrive Sdk the library internally was making call to WebViewClient for authorization and in that case they have added the code

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,     SslError error) {
    handler.proceed();
}
```

As per googles recommendations you should not proceed it directly. user should notify with security exception.
In OneDrive updated SDK they have removed the nu-necessary implementation of onReceivedSslError. That Solved the problem of uploading APK on Google Play Store.
**If you are using any third party tool or library that implements this call you should update the call with:**

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 builder.setMessage(R.string.notification_error_ssl_cert_invalid);
  builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       handler.proceed();
   }
 });
builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       handler.cancel();
   }
  });
  final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
 dialog.show();
}
```

**or either you can remove if you don't require.**

Answer (score 1):

onReceivedSslError should notify user is going to a page with invalid cert. You should not proceed it directly.

here are the lines from LiveSDK

**This project doesn't include that terrible SSL hack. This library is vastly more security compliant and uses the HTTP libraries as per the latest guidance from the Android documentation.**

ref:1)https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android/issues/31

2)https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Android/issues/63

you can try this.

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
   final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   builder.setMessage(R.string.notification_error_ssl_cert_invalid);
      builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           handler.proceed();
       }
   });
   builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           handler.cancel();
       }
   });
   final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
   dialog.show();
}
```